# How to use JQuery to test Javascript Engine speed (to optimize features)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, usability

Along the same lines as responsive design, I would like to have users experience a different level of animation (or none at all) depending on the speed of the JavaScript engine in their browser. How could I use JQuery to detect or predict processing speed on a client?

Comment: Why jQuery? It doesn't contain API for benchmarking. It would make more sense to write your own function, or use a third-party benchmarking script...

Comment: Does not have to be JQuery it can be straight JS. I suggest JQuery in case their might be a feature in the library for this use case. In addition, I did not want people suggesting to use prototype or YUI GUI, etc...